# How to add multiple controller in single page in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I am new to AngularJS I have a problem with this code. I want to add multiple controller in single `ng-app`. But it execute first one. Why not second one?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="myapp">
<head>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angul /1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div ng-controller="cont1">
        <input type="text" ng-model="fullname">
        {{fullname}}
    </div>
    <div ng-controller="cont2">
        <input type="text" ng-model="fname">
        {{fname}}
    </div>
    <script>
        var app = angular.module("myapp", []);
        app.controller('cont1', function ($scope) {
            $scope.fullname = "";
        });
        var new = angular.module('myapp', []);
        new.controller('cont2', function ($scope) {
            $scope.fname = "";
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Because you are overwriting the first `myapp` module when you do `var new= angular.module('myapp',[]);`.

Your code should be:

```
var app = angular.module("myapp", []);
app.controller('cont1', function($scope) {
  $scope.fullname = "";
});
app.controller('cont2', function($scope) {
  $scope.fname = "";
});
```

or

```
var app = angular.module("myapp", []);
app.controller('cont1', function($scope) {
  $scope.fullname = "";
});
angular.module("myapp").controller('cont2', function($scope) {
  $scope.fname = "";
});
```

The second parameter`[]` passed to `module()` makes the difference

Comment: you totaly right about the parameter []. but this syntax is better ( don't use var app)  : `angular.module("myapp", []);
angular.module("myapp").controller('cont1', function($scope) {...});
angular.module("myapp").controller('cont2', function($scope) {...});`

Answer (score 1):

To best way to define controllers, directives, factories etc... is

define your modules names in a separate file

**app.module.js**

```
angular.module("myapp",[]); // inside [] you define your module dependencies
```

for controllers create separate file (depending on your requirement even you can create 1 file for 1 controller)

**some.controller.js**

```
angular.module("myapp").controller('someCtrl'['$scope', function($scope){

}]);

angular.module("myapp").controller('someOtherCtrl'['$scope', function($scope){

}]);
```

**NOTE:**

Two types you can write controller

**TYPE1** (not recomended)

```
.controller('ctrlName', function($scope){

});
```

**TYPE2** (recomended)

```
.controller('ctrlName', ['$scope', function($scope){

}]);
```

**Reason**

So as you can see in the TYPE2 we are passing controller dependencies in an array, so when we compile our program angular will give the name as eg:a to $scope inside function() and treat it as $scope.

With the TYPE1 you need to follow specific order while defining controller dependency otherwise angular will through error because in this approach angular simply treats first dependency as $rootscope, second as $scope and so on....

**For Eg:**

you can't pass dependencies to your controller like this

```
.controller('ctrlName', function($http, $scope) {

});
```

this will throw error

if you define like

```
.controller('ctrlName', function($scope, $http) {

    });
```

this will work fine since its in order that angular wants.

Answer (score 0):

You can define multiple controllers in a single module in this way also:

```
    angular.module("myapp",[]);
    .controller('cont1',function($scope){
      $scope.fullname="";
       });

   .controller('cont2',function($scope){
    $scope.fname="";
    });
```

When you are defining modules, don't use `var`. You can find some of the Angular best practices here: [Angular Style Guide/Best Practices](https://github.com/johnpapa/angular-styleguide#single-responsibility)